# 1980's/1990's movie starting with exploring a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

I remember watching a movie on VHS between 1990-1995 that starts with the exploration of a spaceship where there are mummified astronauts in spacesuits.

I seem to recall a large spaceship and a pan of the area without dialog where the astronaut is in a spacesuit/rocket pack chair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I assume, since you didn't mention otherwise, that this is live-action.  Was there any dialog?  (Or was there voice-over narration?)  Was it in English?  Was the spaceship in space or on a planet?

Comment: Lifeforce? Though I don't recall if there are mummified astronauts there (and I really don't want to re-watch it to see)

Comment: The Space Jockey scene in Alien?

Comment: If you know of any films that aren't the one you're looking for, but have similar scenes, it'd be helpful to list them in your question so as to rule them out of consideration.

Comment: I'd second Lifeforce, Made in 1985. Astronaut with jetpack, large spaceship. However, the mummified aliens are large bats without spacesuits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the opening to *Lifeforce* (1985), as [andrewsi said in a comment above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283696/1980s-1990s-movie-starting-with-exploring-a-spaceship#comment779750_283696). They mount a rescue mission to a space shuttle that lost contact, all the astronauts except one are dead and desiccated, and there are sexy space vampires in the cargo.

[image]

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding one or more relevant images or video clips.

Comment: Agree that a clip of sexy space vampires is warranted.